# Only LegacyIAccessible pattern available in DevExpress

Tags: c#, automation, devexpress, ui-automation

I want to create some interactions between my automation app and DevExpress controls, but it seems the only pattern most of them support is LegacyIAccessible pattern, without default action even defined. So my question is - how can I click on that element when there is no way to call InvokePattern? Can I do it using only available? I'm using UIA Com Wrapper.

Comment: It is not quite clear from your description which platform you are using(WPF/WinForms???), which control your are clicking and which elements of these control you are hitting... Please clarify these points with more details and screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, you can always use [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput) to generate mouse clicks.  You can use the BoundingRectangle property to get the bounds, and then use the midpoint for a clickable point.  (I'm assuming that the ClickablePoint property isn't set either.)